# Simplifying Factorial

Tags: java, factorial

This is my code for displaying factorial. But I think it's too long. How can I make my code shorter? Feedback will be appreciated. Thank you!

This is the sample output:

6! = 5*4*3*2*1 = 720

This is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
public class Factorial {

   public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException
   {
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

int f = 1;

System.out.print("Enter number: ");
int num = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
int temp3 = num;
String temp [] = new String [num];

while (num >= 1)
{
    f = num * f;
    num = num - 1;
}

   for (int x=1; x<temp3; x++)
   {
    temp[x]= "" + Integer.toString(x);
   }


StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
for (int i = temp3 - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
    result.append(temp[i]);

    if (i > 1)
    {
        result.append("*");
    }

}

   System.out.print(temp3 + "! = " + result.toString() + " = " + f);

   }


}
```

Comment: code review -> http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: 6! = 6*5*4*3*2*1 = 720 ???

Comment: Note that 13! will overflow an `int` type, 21! will overflow a `long` type. Consider using a type optimised for large integers?

Comment: From the JavaDoc of `StringBuffer`: *As of release JDK 5, this class has been supplemented with an equivalent class designed for use by a single thread, StringBuilder. The StringBuilder class should generally be used in preference to this one, as it supports all of the same operations but it is faster, as it performs no synchronization.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than making your code **shorter**, focus on **readability**

Some things that you need to fix before making it shorter

1. Indendation
2. Variable naming: temp, x, f etc. do not make sense
3. Using correct data types: int will cause an overflow

Also try to write code yourself rather than copying snippets

```
for (int i = temp3 - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
    result.append(temp[i]);

    if (i > 1)
    {
```

As far as I understand, there are 2 types of people in this world

1. Who start the curly braces on the same line as the condition
2. Who start on the next line

How can you use both within a gap of 3 lines?

Comment: +1 some good advice here. To add, code at 50% of your ability so you can debug at 100%.